# How to call Method of one UI from Another UI without initializing and without making method static. - Vaadin 14

Tags: vaadin

How can we call FirstUI.Java method from SecondUI.java without initializing the FirstUI.java class and without making FirstUI's method static?

1. FirstUI.Java has multiple tabs buttons that need to hide and show depending on what method (defined in FirstUI.java) SecondUI.java.
2. SecondUI.java gets loads in the VerticalLayout present in FirstUI.Java. And is added to the Vertical layout by calling the constructor of the SecondUI.java.
3. If I make FirstUI.Java's method **static** which making buttons of tabs enable/disable we have to make the tab also static (This is what happening in my case). And the whole application starts to create an issue.

Any Solution?

[My code can be accessed from here, all the static methods in this classes needed to be accessed by other classes](https://gofile.io/d/62CLhX)

Any Idea of how these methods can be called from different UI without making them static?

Comment: This seems quite convoluted.  Why not have a builder somewhere that builds what you need and set that via navigation events etc? Structural sharing of components outside e.g. layouts becomes quickly a PITA.  And never ever have static components you plan to add the scenegraph.

Comment: And also please add the important parts of the code. "calling c'tors" sounds alot like there is some inheritance going on.  Also the annotations like @Route would make it more clear, what those "UI"s are and what layouts etc are in use.

Comment: Hi. Cfrick, Thank you for replying, 1. What do you mean to have a builder? 2. As I said, I am not navigating I am loading the SecondUI in the VirticalLayout of FirstUI.java. Do you this for this I need to use Navigate (the problem with navigating is you can not pass POJO as parameter only long, string, int is allowed and that is also only one)? I hope you now understand why using the constructor. Can you help me with any scenario of how builder work? Please.

Comment: Please add the code to the question

Comment: ok just have a look at these: [Explains how the UIs are set and seen and working](https://ibb.co/JqyHBnX) [Exaplain what my SecondUI.java doing with FirstUi.java](https://ibb.co/561980m)

Comment: In my Scenario, this is my UIFirst.java [The whole file won't fit you can download from file from here](https://gofile.io/d/62CLhX)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64265434/edit) the
question and add the relevant code segments.

Answer (score 2):

what your app needs is an event bus mechanism for between UI communication. You're trying to implement things the wrong way with Vaadin. Your original question is just a side effect of the wrong implementation.

Replied to you over email with additional info to resolve the current issues in your app.

-A